# Hitting dead end installing GoDaddy SSL cert into IIS 10 Windows 2016

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, godaddy

Battling this all morning. Our server has an existing GoDaddy SSL cert set to expire. We renewed the cert at godaddy, received the requisite download and proceeded to install.

Fastidiously following these instructions:

https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-iis-10-server-27349

Make it all the way down to step 34, last item, 'SSL Certificate: select your recently installed SSL.' without any problems whatsoever and, boom, the renewal cert is not listed. (The old one is). Have re-run this process about 10x with no change in the results. Pulling hair out. Old one expires Friday.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the new certificate appear in the certificates MMC?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we solved it. Required opening a support incident with GD, generating a fresh CSR, waiting for the verification and files. The second cert package installed without a hitch. Go figure. Honestly don't know what was different.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38 Your story won't go any different deep down inside.